# How can I change the period for Observable.interval, and how can I stop and resume the Observable ticks at runtime

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-java2

is there a way to change the Observable.interval period at runtime?
and is there a way to stop and resume the Observable.interval ticks?
and is there a way to reset the interval period?

actually I'm using the following code to do an action for ever in a period time, but I have no control on it during the run time, I have to stop, resume, rest, and change the period at runtime.

```
Observable.interval(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Observer<Long>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                            Log.i("TAG", "onSubscribe");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(Long aLong) {
                            myMethod();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            Log.i("TAG", "onError");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {
                            Log.i("TAG", "onComplete");
                        }
                    });
```

I have tried to google it to find a solution, but unfortunately I did not find any one, and I need a help or a resource if there is any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is my solution to handle the issue

```
private PublishSubject<Long> newInterval;

// reactive programming using RXJava2
private void prepareObserver() {
    newInterval = PublishSubject.create();

    newInterval.switchMap(currentPeriod ->
            Observable.interval(currentPeriod, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
    )
            .doOnNext(v -> runOnUiThread(this::pagerForeword))
            .subscribe();

    newInterval.onNext(period);
}
```

and to reset the interval period I call

```
newInterval.onNext(period);
```

and you can find the full solution over the following resource tutorial [here](https://github.com/aomari/AndroidViewPagerRxJava)

I hope this be useful!

Comment: I tried this but I dont know what I'm doing wrong. Initial interval is 5000 milliseconds. when I change to 20000 milliseconds, the 5k one is still running. the interval period doesn't reset

Answer (score 8):

As @DDH indicated, perhaps the simplest way is to cancel an ongoing interval and start a new flow completely.

However, if you have to maintain the chain below the interval for some reason, you can switch to a new interval via the `switchMap` operator, triggered by a `PublishSubject` for example:

```
PublishSubject<Long> newInterval = PublishSubject.create();

newInterval.switchMap(currentPeriod ->
    Observable.interval(currentPeriod, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
)
.doOnNext(v -> { /* background work */ })
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(/* ... */);

newInterval.onNext(1000L);

// sometime later

newInterval.onNext(200L);
```

Comment: First of all Thanks @akarnokd. and I have some small questions, do onNext working on background, so why we have added  observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()), second question, about the subscribe(/* ... */), if I implemented new Observer<Long>() then it will not work, to work I have to leave it empty. could you describe please?

Comment: Why do you have it in your original example? What do you mean by not working?

Comment: Sorry, no need to use it, I have fixed it and I will write the solution after I push it to the github. your solution has fixed the problem, but I have made some small changes to handle my case in clear way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what did you mean by " I have to stop, resume, rest, and change the period at runtime."
But you can dispose subscription and reinit observable with new period on runtime:

```
    Disposable d = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<Long>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Long aLong) throws Exception {

                }
            });
    d.dispose();
```